# Calculating XIRR result

Tags: excel, google-sheets, finance, xirr

I have an instrument that is giving me 8% interest. (Calculated as 8%/12 every month but credited once a year).

**What should be the XIRR for this after 2 years.**

According to me it should be 8% but for the entries I made both google sheet and excel is showing it as 17%. Why is it so ? What mistake am I doing?

93672 is the Sum of all values (positive and negative).

| Dates | Cashflow |
| --- | --- |
| 1/4/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/5/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/6/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/7/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/8/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/9/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/10/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/11/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/12/2021 | -3600 |
| 1/1/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/2/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/3/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/3/2022 | 1872 |
| 1/4/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/5/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/6/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/7/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/8/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/9/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/10/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/11/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/12/2022 | -3600 |
| 1/1/2023 | -3600 |
| 1/2/2023 | -3600 |
| 1/3/2023 | -3600 |
| 1/3/2023 | 5478 |
| 1/3/2023 | 93750 |

The formula I applied is xirr(B2:B28,A2:A28) Column B is cashflow, Column A is Dates

[image: Excel image of data]

Comment: Editing is better than deleting and re-posting.

Comment: Can you please provide a clear example of your data in a spreadsheet? The last row from the data in the table vs. the screenshot you provided aren't the same.

Comment: I have corrected the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question uses an incorrect method for the calculation of XIRR:

The correct method:

`=xirr(Q2:Q26,P2:P26,0.08)`

Note: interest of $1872 and $5478 is **NOT** included in the XIRR calculation.

---

**XIRR**

[image: snapshop]

---

**Longhand calculation**

Interest formula in Column N: `=round(M2*$G$3/12*1,)`

[image: longhand]

Comment: So I am not supposed to include interest (1872 and 5477) as separate items?

Comment: Correct. The interest doesn't represent a "cash flow" ([within the meaning of the formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093266?sjid=3191843103206748926-AP)). Also, the final payment of 93,750 includes interest; so if you were to include $1,872 and $5,477 then you'd be double counting.

Comment: Thanks Tedinoz. Another question if 40% of my portfolio is having 6% XIRR  and 30%  is having 10% XIRR  and rest is 6%. XIRR . Can I use weighted average to calculate my overall portfolio XIRR?

Comment: Hmm. That's really a question outside my skillset. It _sounds_ right to me but, hey, what would I know. Knowing how to drive a spreadsheet doesn't make one a financial expert.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like answer to my question is No